# Stack and git are incompatible in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, git, haskell, haskell-stack

I have been using Stack for dependencies management and building system for Haskell programs in Windows 7 Pro without problems.

```
    stack --version
    Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
```

I have recently installed git for Windows, and Stack cannot download lts files anymore. It seems that Stack is trying using the new git client instead of the internal one.

```
git --version
git version 2.13.3.windows.1
```

The error I get when I try to create a new project is the following:

```
C:\proj>stack new newProject
Downloading template "new-template" to create project "newProject" in newProject\ ...
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- newProject\newProject.cabal

Selecting the best among 11 snapshots...

Fetching package index ...fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
Process exited with ExitFailure 128: C:\dev\git\apps\Git\cmd\git.EXE --git-dir=.git fetch --tags
Failed to fetch package index, retrying.
removeDirectoryRecursive: permission denied (Acceso denegado.)
```

If I rename the directory where git is installed, Stack works again. But that is not a real solution.
Any help will be apreciated

Comment: This looks like the old problem with deleting read-only files on Windows. Try removing the `indicies` folder. Find out where it is by `stack -v new proj`.

Comment: Normally, it would be under `c:\sr`.